# Noob: How to echo out <string>

Tags: php

i tried to echo out #include  but it kept showing only "#include ; "

```
<html>
<body>
<?php $note = " #include <string>; ";
echo $note;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're viewing it in the browser I presume.  The browser is misinterpreting that as an HTML tag. View your page source, and it will be there. You need to use `htmlspecialchars()` as in `echo htmlspecialchars($note);`

Comment: Take a look at the source of the page.  Your browser things `<string>` is an html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of the page in your browser will tell you that  is actually there: it's just that everything between < and > is interpreted by the browser as a tag, in this case an unknown tag called "string".

So, you'll need to escape the "special" characters < and >:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php $note = " #include <string>; ";
  echo htmlentities($note);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's html. If you want literal `<` or `>` to show up in your rendered text, you have to use proper HTML methods:

```
echo "#include &lt;string&gt;"
```

or if you want to automate it:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('#include <string>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser is seeing a tag called `<string>` and is ignoring it as it isn't a valid tag.  You need to use the HTML entities for "<" and ">".  Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php $note = " #include <string>; ";
echo htmlspecialchars($note);
?>
</body>
</html>
```